# Find the longest line starting with specific word(s)

Tags: regex

In my project I try to find the occurrences with the longest method name.

For example

```
private function anyVeryLongMethodName($param ...);

public function anyEvenLongerMethodName()

protected function ...()
```

I already found something like

```
^.{100,}$
```

which will not show exactly the longest match but will give a manageable result set when playing around with the count

Unfortunately, it does not consider starting with `public/private/protected function`

Is there an appropriate regex doing this job?

Comment: You cannot get max length match using pure regex. You need to get all matches and then get the max length match in your code.

Comment: As you see in the question, I am already aware getting not the one with the max length but getting a set of results with for example 100+ length is also fine ... the provided code is doing it already but does not consider specific words in the beginning of the line

Comment: It does match any function but the resultset is huge now ... any way to restrict it to a minimum length like ``^.{100,}$``does?

Comment: Seems like ``\b(?:public|private|protected)\s+function\s+(.{100,})\h*\(``will do it in a usable way

Comment: `\b(?:public|private|protected)\s+function\s+(\w{100,})\h*\(` would get all 100+ length words

Comment: exactly what i want ... would you write an answer that can be accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex to match function names that are preceded by certain keywords and are 100 or more in length:

```sh
\b(?:public|private|protected)\s+function\s+(\w{100,})\s*\(
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UtR0jG/1)

**Regex Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?:public|private|protected)`: Match one of the 3 words
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `function`: Match text `function`
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(\w{100,})`: Match 100 or more word characters in capture group #1
- `\s*\(`: Match 0+ whitespaces followed by a `(`